R plot shown from interactive shell, but not from script
While trying to plot Shapley values in R with shapviz, I am obeserving the weird behaviour that the following code display the plot when called in the interactive R shell, but not when called in a script run with source("script.r"):
shp <- shapviz(s)
sv_importance(shp)

Apparently, shapviz uses ggplot2, with which I am unfamiliar. Is there some magic required to make a ggplot2-plot appear when it is drawn in a script?

In functions and scripts you can try to wrap that last expression in plot()

Yes, that did the trick. Would you mind turning your comment into an answer so that I can accept it? Ideally also with a brief explanation why the plot does not show up in the script.

I would but I don't really have a clear answer why. Something about an implicit print() generic deciding to plot it on the default graphics device or something! But in general it seems to hide the plot otherwise when its wrapped in a local environment like in a function. Glad it worked out for you.
